# MySQL : how to add foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following code in mysql.

```
create table employee(
    e_id int(10) not null auto_increment,
    user_id int(10),
    usertype_id default 1,
    name varchar(50),
    primary key (e_id)
);
create table relation(
    r_id int(10) not null auto_increment,
    user_id int(10) not null,
    usertype_id int(10) not null,
    interest_id int(10) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Firstly, i want `user_id` will have the same value as column `e_id`;

And then, i want to add `user_id` and `usertype_id` as an unity in table `relation` as a foreign key for `user_id` and `usertype_id` in table `employee`.

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `user_id` and `usertype_id` in table `relation` as foreign keys for the same columns in table `employee` like this:

```
create table relation(
    r_id int(10) not null auto_increment,
    foreign key user_id references employee(user_id),
    foreign key usertype_id references employee(usertype_id),
    interest_id int(10) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

I can't help you with `e_id` and `user_id` being equal to each other. Honestly, it sounds like a waste of space.

Comment: @thanks vanessa, in fact, i want to add a foreign key for user_id and usertype_id as an unity. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a trigger to guarantee that e_id and user_id contain the same value, but I agree with the previous poster. What's the point?

Comment: @Greg, thanks. I want to use the user_id for other use, and it shouldn't be primary key. So i have to do that. Do you have any ideas?